# i am not able to delete the one row of react-final-form-array and it reset is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

go through this code and add customers and delete it. it gives an error.

https://codesandbox.io/s/array-fields-7x1n3

Answer (score 0):

Define like this

```
<span
    onClick={() => deleteIt(index)}>
     ❌
 </span>
```

function code

```
const deleteIt=index=>{
    console.log(index)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by making your `remove` `span` tag like this:

```
<span type="button"
      onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}> 
❌ 
</span>
```

Basically I made the `span` a `button`. I think the problem lies in the definition of the `validator` of `final-form-arrays`, maybe it's something about the difference between `span` and `button` `onClick` event but I'm not sure..